# Executing function when pop-up window with redirects inside is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm showing the pop-up window from the page. The popup has one page, which then redirects to another (LinkedIn authorization one, to be clear), and then, after the successful login, the initial authorization page is opened again.
I want to reload the parent page when the popup is closed, but cannot do this.
The code is the following:

```
function OpenAuthorizePopUp() {
    var w = window.open("AuthorizePage.aspx", "PopUp", "width=450,height=540");
    w.onunload = function () {
        SubmitPage();
    };

    return false;
}
function SubmitPage() {
    alert("SUBMIT!");
}
```

The issue here is that SubmitPage() function is called not when window is closed, but just after the popup is shown. I guess it's because of redirect inside the popup, and unload is raised when we move from the first page.

Is there a way to catch the actual moment when the window is closed in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Instead of accessing parent window with window.parent, wrote

```
opener.location.reload(true);
```

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

So the flow of the popup goes like this:

`1. Your page -> 2. LinkedIn Page -> 3. Your Page`

Can you change the URL that LinkedIn sends you back to (3.) ? If so, have LinkedIn send you back to a page that has `window.onunload = window.parent.SubmitPage;` on it.

If you can't- ie, LinkedIn always sends you back to the first page- make the third page test for a successful connection to LinkedIn and if it's present, execute `window.onunload = window.parent.SubmitPage;`.

A possible improvement to your idea would be to just have the "success" page call `window.parent.SubmitPage();` and then `window.close();` since you won't need the popup anymore.

Comment: As I see in the debugger, after the popup redirects from linkedin page back to my auth page, the window.parent.name becomes "PopUp". So it looks like after the redirect window.parent changes. When I call window.parent.SubmitPage(), I get TypeError.

Comment: maybe try `window.parent.parent`? If you're stumped, find another site that uses a LinkedIn login and see how they manage it.

Comment: Tried this, as well as window.parent.parent.parent :). Still doesn't work and just returns PopUp window.